# JMeter Time Lapse

Tags: jmeter

I need JMeter to simulate 28 days of activity (via altering time stamps) in under 1 day. There is is time function, but it doesn't look like there is one that supports anything other than current time. I also don't want to fake the dates because things like leap years and what month it is will make it incorrect.

So how can I get a time format as a delta of the current time (in milliseconds from epoch), and/or what is the best way to run a 1 day load test as if time was going 28 times faster?

UPDATE:
Thanks Dmitri T! I was able to modify your answer to what I needed (I have to restrict what hours events occur between 8am and 5pm)

For those that need it, I used the following in a JSR223 PreProcessor

```js
timestamp=new Date();
timestamp.setDate(timestamp.getDate() - Math.floor(Math.random() * (28)));
timestamp.setHours(8,0,0,0);
timestamp.setTime(timestamp.getTime() +  Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000*60*60*9)));
vars.put("TIMESTAMP", timestamp.toISOString());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simulate this using [__time()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) and [__longSum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__longSum) functions combination like:

- Now: `${__time(,)}` - I guess you are already aware of it
- Now + 28 days: `${__longSum(${__time(,)},2419200000,)}` - where 2419200000 is

  ```
  1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 28 
   ^     ^    ^    ^     ^
   ms   sec  min  hour  day
  ```

If Unix timestamps don't play for your for some reason you can use __javaScript() function to convert them to human-readable format like:

```
${__javaScript(new Date(${__longSum(${__time(,)},2419200000,)}),)}
```

Demo:

[image: Functions time demo]

References:

1. [Functions and Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
2. [The Function Helper Dialog](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper)
3. [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii)